# Why is my javascript not getting the element by its id?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

I have an aspx page and I am trying to hide a table row when the country selected in a drop down list is "US". I keep getting a null reference error (or the javascript equivalent) because it can't find one of the elements.

Here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cntryslct() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("staterow");
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("country");
        elem.style.display = (dropdown.value; != "US") ? "none" : "";


    };
</script>
```

For some reason it can't find the element "country".

Here is what "country" looks like:

```
<tr>
    <th class="style1"><strong>Country: </strong></th>
    <th class="style2">
        <asp:DropDownList onchange="cntryslct()" id = "country" ...>stuff</asp:DropDownList>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Not sure if it matters, but "country" is after "staterow", the element being hidden and shown.

Why can it not find the element by its id? Is it because the element is also the element where the script is being called?

Comment: It's because the ID changes after page renderization. You should use ClientID="Static" on your Dropdownlist

Comment: When dealing with js always look at the rendered html (browser, view source) not the raw aspx.  I imagine your `id` is not at all what you think it is once it is processed.

Comment: Depending on what browser you are using, you can right click the select element in question and click "Inspect Element". Here you can inspect if it actually has an id of "country".

Comment: You have an extra ";" in the condition, did u mean `elem.style.display = (dropdown.value != "US" ? "none" : "");` ?

Comment: yeah i noticed that after Yuriy, but thank you cr0ss that solved it. I am not too experienced with javascript, html, and web design in general. You should make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID of all of your ASPX components changes after page renderization.

You have two alternatives:

1) Set the property ClientID="Static" of your ASPX components;

2) Or get the [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at runtime, for example:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById('<%= country.ClientID %>');
```