# Add Value to Listbox in User Control Using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-controls, listbox, webusercontrol

I am able to add value to textbox in User control using jQuery. Below is my code:

```
$("input[id*=txtApproverEmail]").val("EmailAddress");
```

How to add or append value to listbox in user control using jQuery or javascript?

Below is my user control:

```
<tr>
    <td>Select Approver:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtApproverEmail" runat="server" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <img id="imgCOApproverEmail" src="../Images/Binoculars.png" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Carbon Copy To:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstCCTo" runat="server" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" Width="310px"></asp:ListBox>
        <img id="imgCOApproverEmailCCTo" src="../Images/Binoculars.png" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select').append('<option>New value</option>');
```

Or

```
$('select[id*=lstCCTo]').append('<option>New value</option>');
```

Comment: It is not working. Unable to detect the usercontrol listbox ID like this

Comment: the ID of any ASPX components change after page renderization. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768106/why-is-my-javascript-not-getting-the-element-by-its-id/23768231#23768231

Comment: If you have only one `listbox` then you can do `$('select').append('<option>New value</option>');` or try `$('select[id*=lstCCTo]').append('<option>New value</option>');`